# Spring integration. Want to use HTTPS

Tags: spring, rest, https, spring-integration

I'm using Spring Integration - HTTP Adaptor.

Now, I want to make it HTTPS. Please let me know how to implement it.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean on the client (outbound) side, simply use an https://... url.

If you mean on the server (inbound) side, then configure your servlet container to use SSL.